# List not converting to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Below is the error i getting :

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List[StoredProcedureEF_MVC.tbl_users]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[StoredProcedureEF_MVC.Models.User]'.

I have tried a lot but don't know where i was doing wrong, no luck from last two days. I am learning MVC, so sorry if you got some stupid mistake.

My Model :

```
namespace StoredProcedureEF_MVC.Models
{
    [Table("tbl_users")]
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Username {get;set;}
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

VIEW:

```
@model IEnumerable<StoredProcedureEF_MVC.Models.User> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Delete";
}

@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model);
}

@grid.GetHtml(
  columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("UserID"),
    grid.Column("Username"),
    grid.Column("Email"),
    grid.Column(
      format: (item) => Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteUser", new {id=item.UserID })
    )
  )
)
```

CONTROLLER ACTION:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete()
{
  SPEFMVCEntities conn = new SPEFMVCEntities();
  var result = (from p in conn.tbl_users select p).ToList();
  return View(result);
}
```

Comment: Well presumably `conn.tbl_users` is declared to return an `IQueryable<StoredProcedureEF_MVC.tbl_users>`, not an `StoredProcedureEF_MVC.Models.User`... How did you expect the conversion to be performed from one to the other?

Comment: `StoredProcedureEF_MVC.tbl_users` is not the same type as `StoredProcedureEF_MVC.Models.User`

Comment: @Jon Skeet, so what's the solution ?

Comment: Potentially write a projection from one type to the other. Potentially change to only have one type at all. We don't know enough about your system to say. Do you understand the error though?

Comment: @Jon Skeet, thanks for your help, found solution.

Comment: I am not expert in Asp.net but why u need to call .ToList() with your result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var result = conn.tbl_users.Select(c => new StoredProcedureEF_MVC.Models.User
{
    UserId  = c.UserId,
    UserName = c.UserName, 
    Email = c.Email
}).ToList();
return View(result);
```

Comment: This will work for sure, but I don't think that's the right way to do this.

Comment: Not even "for sure" - you may need an `AsEnumerable` in there (or an intermediate projection to an anonymous type, followed by AsEnumerable, followed by this projection) as otherwise the LINQ provider may complain that it doesn't "know" about `Models.User`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your controller method to this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Delete()
{
  SPEFMVCEntities conn = new SPEFMVCEntities();
  var result = (from p in conn.tbl_users select p as StoredProcedureEF_MVC.Models.User).ToList();
  return View(result);
}
```

Comment: NO LUCK : ERROR ---Unable to cast the type 'StoredProcedureEF_MVC.tbl_users' to type 'StoredProcedureEF_MVC.Models.User'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: And have you tried changing `conn.tbl_users` to `conn.User` or `conn.Users`? Does that work?